# RoR: how to get the creation timestamp in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class Event where I need a method that compares the current date to the date the Event was created. Can you tell me how to access the created_at timestamp the scaffold created for the Event database table?

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location, :name


  def isInsertedLongAgo
      # current date - insertion date >= 90 days
  end


end
```

Comment: If you want to follow standard Ruby conventions, you should probably name the method `inserted_long_ago?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as any other attribute - just call it:

```
def isInsertedLongAgo
  # current date - insertion date >= 90 days
  Time.now - created_at >= 90.days
end
```

Comment: `attr_accessible` has nothing to do with this. You probably don't want to allow anyone to mass-assign values on top of `created_at`!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can acces created at using created_at field `self.created_at`,
At the time of  scaffold time stamp  is created which create created_at,updated_at
You can directly access those variables.
**replace insertion date with created_at**